# Creating comparison SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `link_clicks` (
    `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Clicked` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `State` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT '',
    INDEX `LinkID` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

What I need to do is to create a single script where I can enter 4 dates and list the values between the second 2 dates next to the values between the first 2 dates.

Kind of like this:

```
State  Oct 27-Nov 2  Nov 3-Nov 9
AL         13           18
AR         6            14
AZ         18           32
```

Here is some sample data since Oct 27:

```
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86503, 'AL', '2014-11-13 15:36:13');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86502, 'AL', '2014-11-13 15:33:24');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86496, 'AL', '2014-11-13 14:53:03');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86477, 'AZ', '2014-11-13 13:06:34');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86462, 'AZ', '2014-11-13 11:21:15');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86406, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 15:55:00');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86402, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 14:52:35');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86401, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 14:51:22');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86400, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 14:49:23');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86395, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 14:29:43');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86393, 'AL', '2014-11-12 14:21:42');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86367, 'AL', '2014-11-12 11:40:38');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86353, 'AR', '2014-11-12 10:13:01');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86351, 'AR', '2014-11-12 10:10:35');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86347, 'AR', '2014-11-12 09:49:37');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86346, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 09:46:42');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86314, 'AZ', '2014-11-12 07:37:42');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86278, 'AR', '2014-11-11 15:22:34');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86277, 'AR', '2014-11-11 15:20:41');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86242, 'AZ', '2014-11-11 12:24:32');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86228, 'AZ', '2014-11-11 11:10:45');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86224, 'AZ', '2014-11-11 10:35:30');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86201, 'AL', '2014-11-11 08:59:37');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86199, 'AL', '2014-11-11 08:55:42');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86187, 'AR', '2014-11-11 08:31:15');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86166, 'AR', '2014-11-10 16:58:24');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86087, 'AZ', '2014-11-10 11:32:50');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86084, 'AZ', '2014-11-10 11:14:47');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86048, 'AZ', '2014-11-10 09:45:02');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (86025, 'AR', '2014-11-10 08:36:36');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85984, 'AZ', '2014-11-07 18:48:46');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85979, 'AZ', '2014-11-07 16:25:53');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85977, 'AZ', '2014-11-07 16:21:25');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85920, 'AR', '2014-11-07 10:32:43');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85864, 'AZ', '2014-11-06 19:35:03');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85861, 'AZ', '2014-11-06 17:25:41');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85814, 'AZ', '2014-11-06 12:32:33');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85813, 'AZ', '2014-11-06 12:27:04');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85757, 'AR', '2014-11-06 09:13:04');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85754, 'AZ', '2014-11-06 08:53:52');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85733, 'AZ', '2014-11-05 17:42:32');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85710, 'AL', '2014-11-05 15:00:36');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85708, 'AL', '2014-11-05 14:59:25');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85703, 'AZ', '2014-11-05 14:47:45');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85661, 'AZ', '2014-11-05 11:39:20');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85660, 'AL', '2014-11-05 11:38:30');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85659, 'AL', '2014-11-05 11:34:21');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85657, 'AR', '2014-11-05 11:26:46');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85639, 'AZ', '2014-11-05 10:21:12');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85568, 'AL', '2014-11-04 14:12:47');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85526, 'AL', '2014-11-04 11:11:48');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85515, 'AL', '2014-11-04 10:38:18');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85479, 'AZ', '2014-11-04 08:56:22');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85415, 'AL', '2014-11-03 14:00:36');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85405, 'AR', '2014-11-03 13:29:22');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85402, 'AZ', '2014-11-03 13:24:57');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85382, 'AZ', '2014-11-03 12:17:41');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85374, 'AZ', '2014-11-03 12:00:26');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85314, 'AL', '2014-11-03 09:56:04');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85304, 'AL', '2014-11-03 09:42:24');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85300, 'AR', '2014-11-03 09:35:10');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85274, 'AZ', '2014-11-03 09:05:46');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85239, 'AR', '2014-11-02 15:53:02');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85227, 'AL', '2014-11-02 08:50:35');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85168, 'AL', '2014-10-31 13:17:53');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85164, 'AL', '2014-10-31 13:15:17');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85101, 'AL', '2014-10-30 21:03:16');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85097, 'AZ', '2014-10-30 16:30:03');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85060, 'AL', '2014-10-30 12:35:46');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85059, 'AL', '2014-10-30 12:35:18');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85057, 'AZ', '2014-10-30 12:30:08');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85056, 'AZ', '2014-10-30 12:27:28');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85043, 'AZ', '2014-10-30 10:55:13');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (85041, 'AZ', '2014-10-30 10:49:59');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84995, 'AL', '2014-10-29 16:42:02');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84992, 'AZ', '2014-10-29 16:22:02');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84987, 'AR', '2014-10-29 15:38:55');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84968, 'AR', '2014-10-29 13:44:04');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84955, 'AZ', '2014-10-29 12:11:24');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84937, 'AR', '2014-10-29 10:30:42');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84919, 'AR', '2014-10-29 09:02:50');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84892, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 18:17:37');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84891, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 17:48:08');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84890, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 17:39:03');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84868, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 15:16:55');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84865, 'AL', '2014-10-28 14:58:56');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84861, 'AL', '2014-10-28 14:48:20');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84843, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 12:43:52');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84835, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 11:28:26');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84817, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 10:25:02');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84815, 'AZ', '2014-10-28 10:19:21');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84808, 'AL', '2014-10-28 09:43:24');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84807, 'AL', '2014-10-28 09:37:45');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84779, 'AL', '2014-10-27 21:25:07');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84756, 'AL', '2014-10-27 15:03:41');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84739, 'AL', '2014-10-27 13:54:27');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84711, 'AR', '2014-10-27 11:12:50');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84692, 'AZ', '2014-10-27 09:53:43');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84683, 'AR', '2014-10-27 09:16:57');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84682, 'AZ', '2014-10-27 09:11:02');
INSERT INTO `link_clicks` (`ID`, `State`, `clicked`) VALUES (84679, 'AZ', '2014-10-27 09:06:16');
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: look at pivot tables

Comment: More info, please @MarshallTigerus. Can a pivot be made from a single table?

Comment: @MB34 there's no reason you can't that I know of.  Just google MySQL pivot table and you should find all the info you need

Comment: Some real help you are, Marshall. I came here wanting specifics, I could Google all day and not find exactly what I want. Thanks a lot. The purpose of this site is to help, not tell people to RTFM or Google it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to issue two queries, one for each date range:

```
SELECT state, COUNT(id)
FROM link_clicks
WHERE Clicked BETWEEN firstDate AND secondDate
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state
```

This query should yield you a list of all states that have been clicked on between `firstDate` and `secondDate`. If you need the query to always return all states (even those that weren't clicked at all in the desired period) you need to perform a `LEFT JOIN` from your `state` table (if such table exists).

Comment: The question asked for a single parametized query.

Comment: Actually, it didn't. You stated you need "to create a single script", not a single query.